# Strings with maths operator do not work here

Tags: python, math

I am new to Python so I seem to fail to get the following program run

```
    import random
num1=0
num2=0

num1=int(random.randint(1,20))
num2=int(random.randint(1,20))
result=0
opr = ("*", "-", "+", "/")
print(random.choice(opr))
print(num1,num2)

if opr=="*":
    result = num1 * num2
if opr=="+":
    result = num1 + num2
if opr=="-":
    result = num1 - num2
if opr=="/":
    result = num1 / num2    
    print(result)
```

Comment: `import python` should at least start at column 1.

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: A little `print(opr)` before the conditionals would show you what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made two changes to your code and it works as you expected.

1. You are not saving the random `opr` to the new variable. You are
   trying to print the random `opr` using this
   `print(random.choice(opr))`, which will print the random `opr` but
   Its value has always been a tuple.
2. I just changed if condition to `if and elf` so that If first condition matches It won't check other

```
import random
num1=0
num2=0

num1=int(random.randint(1,20))
num2=int(random.randint(1,20))
result=0
opr = ("*", "-", "+", "/")

print(num1,num2)
new_opr = random.choice(opr)
print(new_opr)


if new_opr=="*":
    result = num1 * num2
elif new_opr=="+":
    result = num1 + num2
elif new_opr=="-":
    result = num1 - num2
elif new_opr=="/":
    result = num1 / num2    
print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

opr is always the list of operators. So your if statements never evaluate to true. Change this:

```
opr = ("*", "-", "+", "/")
print(random.choice(opr))
```

To this:

```
opr_list = ("*", "-", "+", "/")
opr = random.choice(opr_list)
print(opr)
```

And your code will work.

Answer (score 1):

`opr` still refers to the entire tuple of the 4 operators - so it's not going to pass any of the `if` checks. You need to set a new variable (or even `opr` itself) to `random.choice(opr)` and use this in the `if` statements.

Answer (score 1):

Several things from your code:

---

**First**, you don't need to initialize your variables to affect a value straight after. You can change:

```py
num1=0
num2=0

num1=int(random.randint(1,20))
num2=int(random.randint(1,20))
```

to

```py
num1=int(random.randint(1,20))
num2=int(random.randint(1,20))
```

(*and actually, I would change the names `num1` and `num2` to something different since these have a quite broad meaning*).

---

**Second**, you initialize `opr` with a `tuple` and only print the random choice, never affect it.

Instead of:

```py
opr = ("*", "-", "+", "/")
print(random.choice(opr))
```

You should do:

```py
opr = ("*", "-", "+", "/")
chosen_operator = random.choice(opr)
print(chosen_operator)
```

And actually, you could just do:

```py
chosen_operator = random.choice(("*", "-", "+", "/"))
print(chosen_operator)
```

---

**Finally**, you print the result only in the case where `/` was chosen:

```py
if opr=="*":
    result = num1 * num2
if opr=="+":
    result = num1 + num2
if opr=="-":
    result = num1 - num2
if opr=="/":
    result = num1 / num2    
    print(result)
```

This should be changed for:

```
if opr=="*":
    result = num1 * num2
if opr=="+":
    result = num1 + num2
if opr=="-":
    result = num1 - num2
if opr=="/":
    result = num1 / num2    

# Note that it is not on the same level of indentation than in your code    
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

This code should do the trick

```
import random
num1=0
num2=0

num1=int(random.randint(1,20))
num2=int(random.randint(1,20))
result=0
opr = ("*", "-", "+", "/")
print(num1,num2)

newOpr = random.choice(opr)

print(newOpr)

if newOpr=="*":
    result = num1 * num2
if newOpr=="+":
    result = num1 + num2
if newOpr=="-":
    result = num1 - num2
if newOpr=="/":
    result = num1 / num2    
print(result)
```

The reason you were having your problem is because `random.choice(opr)` does not set `opr` to a random value from your tuple. It just generates one and does nothing with it. Assigning it to a variable allows you to compare/change it's value etc.

Answer (score 1):

You miss-indented it:

```
...
if opr=="/":
    result = num1 / num2    
    print(result)
```

Should become:

```
if opr=="/":
    result = num1 / num2    
print(result) # !!!
```